# Getting WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException while running from CruieControl

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am getting `WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException`:

> Timeout while Internet Explorer busy error while executing my tests via CruiseControl.Net.

Any one have idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we are using TeamCity, we had to disable IE protected mode.

Also, check that user, under which watiN tests are being run can interact with desktop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to accomplish these tasks. I mean how should I check that user under watin can interact or not

Comment: You should check under which user cruise control is running. I am assuming that CC.Net runs your watin tests. So, that user has to have interact with desktop set. If CC.NET runs as service, check under services configuration.

Comment: Thank you. Its done but Still giving me errors as TestFixtureSetUp failed and also it is failing tests while handling popups.

Comment: Try running test with CC.NET user on test server using NUnit console runner (or equivalent, if you are not using NUnit). Or failing that, just replicate development environment on test server (should be pretty close anyways) and try it there. In that case, you can use debugger...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and answered,  but below are some of my observations.

It is possible to run watin tests under a service account 
but the following restrictions/prerequisites apply:

- service must run in desktop interactive mode.  Only available if running as system.
- tests must not create a new windows,  even alert/confirm dialogs
- Ie cannot create a new window, so watin fails when looking for/expecting it to appear.
- ie may show its own warnings, e.g.  Insecure content in a secure Page,  this can cause tests to fail*
- if the tests fail/timeout and the ie instance is forcefully closed,  the next instance may try to restore the previous state.  The tests then appear to fail*
- this can be turned off in the advanced settings.

*from what I've experienced,  usually because the prompt is halting the document from being reported as loading-finished.

Feel free to add with other restrictions /comments.